# php buffering with ob_start: synchronous alternative

Tags: php, synchronization, ob-start

Hy community

I have some troubles with php and could not find a solution. I am currently developing a wordpress plugin, and what I would like to do is to manipulate some content. Using php buffering (`ob_start`) which works fine, but gives me some new troubles. What I am doing is the following (minimalized).

Let's assume that my webpage contains the following text:

```
Hy there, my name is A B, I am living in C with my dog D
```

What the php code is doing: replace a set of strings with the output of a subfunction. Of course, this is just a minimal example.

```
<?php
// -----------------------------------------
// The Function loading some content from a php file
function my_function() {
    ob_start();
    require_once("some_file.php");
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return($content); // Returns new content
}
// -----------------------------------------

// Content of the web page
$content = "Hy there, my name is A B, I am living in C with my dog D";

// Strings to replace (by the content returned by "my_function")
$matches = array("A","B","C","D");

// Looping over the different matches
foreach ( $matches as $match ) {

    // Calling my_function in buffer mode
    $content = str_replace($match,call_user_func("my_function"),$content);


} ?>
```

Well, what happens now is that the buffering is per definition async. As soon as the first `my_function` call is finished, the whole buffer will be cleaned and "`A`" is not replaced by what "`A`" should be replaced, but also contains parts of what "`B`" should be replaced with :). If there is only one thing to replace, that works excellent (only having one `ob_start` process).

Is there any other way to catch output of a include or require call, or to run `ob_*` in a synchronous way? Maybe there would be a way nicer way I have not found. Would be great to get a hint :).

Thanks in advance! Maybe I am completely on the wrong track, but that's how things are getting learned :).

Happy easter,
Reto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use require_once.
But for require_once file has included **ONCE**!
You can use require or include for multiple including.
But this is bad way. Bad architecture.

Comment: Well, that was I thought - bad architecture. But thanks for the reply! Gave me motivation to check again why I am doing what I am doing, and found out that wordpress offers a *shortcode API* ... my fault, sorry, and merry Christmas!

Comment: BTW: the idea I tried is more or less exactly what the wordpress shortcode API is doing. However, when such a shortcode is registered, the problem I had with my hand-made solution does not occur anymore, which is good :).